# php-cgi.exe has 16 and more instances in task manager

Tags: php

Can someone tell me if 16 running processes of **php-cgi.exe** is normal behavior, and if not what might causing that? The server gets a lot of requests and uses HttpRequestPool for sending parallel requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a decent amount of traffic that could be normal. PHP fCGI opens a new task for each request but also reuses currently open tasks to speed the process up and save resources.

Comment: I guess it makes sense then, cause I do get 138 requests at a time, and send out with HttpRequestPool 138 requests to those objects at given times.